# ¿Por qué encuentro el error Constructor indefinido en clase Main?

Tags: java, eclipse, clase, constructor

Estoy haciendo un programa para definir partidos y apuestas y calcular un puntaje sobre los participantes. Ni bien arranco encuentro que para definir "Partido" me dice que el constructor no esta definido.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que interpreto es que esta tomando el constructor por defecto y por eso me tira ese mensaje en consola.

Esta es la clase partido:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesitaria una ayuda para ver que es lo que estoy haciendo mal ya que hace un mes y pico que empece con programacion JAVA y hay cosas que no comprendo.

GRACIAS!!

Comment: Hola Franco, la pregunta debe ser autocontenida, esto es que no dependa de imágenes o enlaces, por favor, edita tu pregunta, elimina las imágenes, y agrega tu código y mensajes de error como texto, así evitarás recibir votos negativos y lograrás que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, gracias, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error que te está dando es correcto, el constructor `Partido(String, String, int, int, String)` no existe.

El constructor que nos estás mostrando es `Partido(Equipo, Equipo, int, int, Resultados)`

Tienes 2 soluciones a esto, o creas un constructor como el primero que comento, o arreglas el `new Partido` pasando los objetos correspondientes como parámetros.